# How to exceed left margin with longtable

Tags: margins, longtable, geometry, tabu

I'm trying to make a longtable that is wider than the textwidth at a certain moment. I've tried different things always ending up with a different problem:

First possibility: If I use the `adjustwidth` environment the `longtabu` does not align correctly. The left margin stays fixed and the right margin gets out of the page. This in contrast, if I do the exact same thing to make a `tabu` (instead of `longtabu`), it works perfectly. I think using the adjustwidth is the best way to go, but I can't manage to get it working.

Second possibility: I've found a solution using the `fullwidth` package. That package does the trick on small `longtable`s, but freezes when I'm trying to do it on my big longtable. The command `\setlength\LTleft{-2cm}` didn't work as well.

The final option I tried was to use `geometry`. But that changes the margin of the whole page thus making a page break which I'm not interested in. The code I used for this was

```
\newgeometry{left=1.2cm}
\begin{longtable}
long table stuff
\end{longtable}
\restoregeometry
```

Here's an example of what I want contra what I get

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\section{This is the original textwidth.}
\lipsum[1]

\section{This is the width I need for my longtabu}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {*{13}{|X[l]} |}
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
\end{tabu}
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{This is what happens}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {*{13}{|X[l]} |}
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
\end{longtabu}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: setting LTleft to be negative would work with the original longtable, do you really need the tabu fork?

Comment: Arh, great, it finally worked! Thanks you. Why doesn't LTleft affect the longtabu? Also, how do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With `longtable` you can do this, if `tabu` has broken it then that's a problem with `tabu`:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\section{This is the original textwidth.}
\lipsum[1]

\section{This is the width I need for my longtabu}

\setlength\LTleft{-1in}
\setlength\LTright{-1in}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{13}{|r}|@{}}
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
01 & 02 & 03 & 04 & 05 & 06 & 07 & 08 & 09 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```