# How to change margins for a table defined in tabularx environment?

Tags: margins, tabularx, leftmargin

I would like to move my table

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llllllllllllllllllllllll}
\caption{Numbers}\\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

to the left and to the top. Could you please help me how to change margins for my table defined in tabularx environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164005/how-to-exceed-left-margin-with-longtable#164022) by David Carlisle:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\section{Text before with original margins}
some text here

\setlength\LTleft{-2cm} % adjust these to your liking
\setlength\LTright{-2cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llllllllllllllllllllllll}
\caption{Numbers}\\\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
\end{tabularx}

\noindent More text with original margins

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you like to accept an answer?

Comment: It would be more practical for me if I could use absolute margins (not related to the original ones). Can I do it somehow?

Answer (score 6):

- do you really need table over more than one page?
- using `tabularx` at least one column had to be of type `X`
- using standard `tabular*` fit table in text area:

[image]

(red lines indicate border of text area)

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    % \usepackage{ltablex}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption{Numbers}
    \noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{24}{l}}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

solution as you ask in question, i.e. considering `ltablex` and expand text width locally (however, table should not be longer than one page):

[image]

(red lines indicate border of page layout)

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

    \usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{ltablex}
    \keepXColumns

    \usepackage[strict]{changepage}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-1.5cm}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{24}{X} }
    \caption{Numbers}   \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{document}
```

**addendum:**
from your comments below i conclude that your mwe, provided in question` is misleading, and question is therefore not clear at all. once you claim your table is 200 rows long and have only 9 columns, in a other that it hasn't 200 rows ...

if you like to have table width equal to text width, and for table use `tabularx` redefined by `ltablex` environment for equal width cells, than you need to make two changes in your mwe:

- replace `c` column specifiers with `X`
- in preamble add command `\keepXColumns`, which will assure that `X` columns will behave the same as at standard `tabularx` (do you aware that using `ltablex` change standard features of `tabularx`?)

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{ltablex}
  \keepXColumns

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{9}{X} }
  \caption{Numbers}   \\
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

(red lines indicate border of page layout)

is this what you looking for?

Comment: than your table should not be wider than text width. it seems that you should consider to rotate table in landscape orientation ...

Comment: @Roloka - If you need to create a table with 9 columns, why did you provide code that creates 24, not 9, columns? And why did you "accept" the other answer, which is clearly incapable of creating a 200-row table?

Comment: @Roloka, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Roloka, what you like to tel me? you should read ma answer first ...